# Normalized word count comparisons

Tags: javascript, python, nlp, word-count

Is there a standard calculations to compare two unordered strings of words.

Id like something normalized though I suppose sense I am taking a series of comparisons I could just normalize with the highest score, though for my particular proposes that would be inefficient.

Examples:

```
c1 = magicFunc("big truck red", "big red truck")
c2 = magicFunc("big red truck", "big red truck")
c3 = magicFunc("big red red truck", "big red truck")
c4 = magicFunc("big blue truck", "big red truck")
```

c1, c2 and c3 have a higher "score" than c4
I'm somewhat indifferent as to c2 vs c3 (but c3 should probably be higher) and c1 should equal c2 as order doesn't matter.

Comment: What is `c5`? And what is an unordered string?

Comment: Also, why is this tagged as both `javascript` and `python`?

Comment: Last question from me: How would you evaluate `magicFunc("big red red truck", "big big red truck")`?

Comment: @aryamccarthy shoulda been c4.

Comment: @aryamccarthy because the code base is in both and I'd be find piping the answer around (I suppose in that sense any language would be ok....)

Comment: @aryamccarthy same

Comment: Is your question addressed? If so, you can help future users by marking the checkbox beside the correct answer. If not, what can be clarified?

Comment: @aryamccarthy "Is there a standard calculation" was part of my question.

Comment: My answer is the size of multiset intersection.

Answer (score 0):

you should check out [_.uniq](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniq)

you could use that function then write your `magicFunc` to compare 2 strings by converting them to arrays and passing them through `_.uniq`.

you could also implement your own by simply [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ing or [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)ing the [.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) up strings.  i would probably start with lodash and see where it takes me.

Comment: What makes this different from the standard library `set` or `collections.Counter`? **EDIT:** Never mind. This question is, for some reason, tagged as both JavaScript and Python.

Comment: @aryamccarthy see my comment for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a stab at it with this:

```
from collections import Counter

def magicFunc(str1, str2):
    bag1, bag2 = Counter(str1.split()), Counter(str2.split())
    overlap = bag1 & bag2
    return sum(overlap.values())
```

On the inputs you give, the scores are 3, 3, 3, and 2.